# Difference between Use Case and User Stories?

Tags: use-case

This always confuses me what is the difference between User Stories and Use Case. Is User Stories a description of how the system shall behave in different conditions?

Comment: Refer this you can understand https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2015/october/user-stories-vs-use-cases

Answer (score 0):

The term *Use Case* has a formal definition in UML:

> Use cases are a means for specifying required usages of a system. Typically, they are used to capture the requirements of a system, that is, what a system is supposed to do.[...]

I.e., you have a formal structure and some other concepts associated with *Use Case* (*actors*, for example).

*User Stories* I've seen it used as an informal way to describe some specific scenario (typically a UI scenario) but it's not formally described in the UML spec.

See [UML Superstructure spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/) (check the proper link) in chapter 16 for more details.

Hope it helps, best regards.